# Compile error: variable not defined (VB Adodb)

Tags: vba, excel

I had a code, which was running perfectly fine yesterday, but now it stopped working and throwing this error:

[image]

I have checked my references, and my activeX box is checked:

[image]

I am really stuck. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to update something?

Comment: Not sure why you think this has anything to do specifically with ActiveX?I would suggest declaring the variable, perhaps `Dim objMyConn`. "Something" changed since yesterday.  If you're not sure, compare to your backup copy (hint hint)  :-)

Comment: It has been working for months, what happened now?

Comment: Probably that you added `Option Explicit` at the top of the module...

Comment: I figured it out - I added Option Explicit which messed up the code, somehow.. I do not know why. I removed it and now it is working... Can anyone explain wtf happened?

Comment: An alternate interpretation is that your code was already messed up, and Option Explicit just pointed it out.Try an internet search on Option Explicit.

Comment: Already did - all the glory it gets and how it is good practice to have it in all code.. But I did not realise if you add it after writing something it messes up order of operations?

Comment: @Miqi180 Put this in the answer box and I will mark it as correct mate...

Comment: @DougGlancy It really stressed me out - fair enough it pointed out errors in my code that have been working before. But I need this to work for now as I fix it and figure out what happened. I am removing Option Explicit for now..

Comment: Go to Tools > Options > Editor Tab and see if the checkbox for "Require Variable Declaration" is ticked. This is what `Option Explicit` does. It has absolutely nothing to do with the order of operations.

Comment: it is already ticked..

Comment: You'll notice then, that when you insert a new module, it automatically says `Option Explicit` at the top. My guess is you that pasted existing code into another module today. Anyway, case closed and happy coding.

Comment: [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDQHD.gif) does **not** 'messed up the code'.

Comment: @Jeeped - I know... My code is not ideal from the start. But as this application is required to run, I removed Option Explicit for now until I fix everything else.

Comment: Perhaps compromise by starting to declare your variables so you don't make matters worse when you have time to start using Option Explicit and other 'best practices'.

Comment: Errors don't show up randomly without anything changing....  But there are some important suggestions above to help you prevent and/or locate issues in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of error typically emerges after adding `Option Explicit` at the top of a module, or after pasting working code without explicitly defined variables into a new module with `Option Explicit` at the top.

Go to Tools > Options > Editor Tab and see if the checkbox for "Require Variable Declaration" is ticked. This is what `Option Explicit` does.